# Array of hours for weekdays - Trying to combine days that are the same

Tags: php

Controlling hours of operation on a website from a database so end users can fiddle with them, and i'm trying to display them all in a neat manner.

Easy enough if i just do every day followed by its hours, however if monday-friday are all the same, i want to display it as monday-friday!

here is my array (call it `$temp`)

some places will open/close twice during a day hence the hours being in another array.

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 08:00am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 08:00am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 08:00am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

    [Thursday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 08:00am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

    [Friday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 08:00am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

    [Saturday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 10:30am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

    [Sunday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [open] => 10:30am
                    [close] => 08:30pm
                )

        )

)
```

Here is the code i have scraped together to try to manipulate the above array into grouping days that are the same:

```
$start = current(array_keys($temp)); //The first open weekday
$end = end(array_keys($temp)); //(SHOULD) only makes the end day the very last day IF they are all the same hours. will reset later.
$last = null;
$count = 0;
foreach($temp as $day => $hours) {
    if($hours == $last) {
        $count++;
        $end = $day; // advance the day thats going to be the end.
        continue; // dont want to hit the resets at the bottom.
    }
    else { 
        if($count = 0) {
            $return['reg_hours'][$yesterday] = $last; //yesterdays hours had no matches so set it alone.
        }
        else { //There is a string of days with the same hours, so concat them
            $return['reg_hours'][$start . ' - ' . $end] = $hours; // i.e. $return['Monday - Thursday'] =  '07:00am - 10:30am'
        }   
        $start = $day; //a new string of hours is starting so reset the start to today.
    }
    $count = 0;
    $yesterday = $day;
    $last = $hours;
}
```

I have commented in my thought process. This works fine if every day has the same hours, however clearly unintended results if hours differ at all. Below is what its returning for the above array:

```
Monday - Sunday 08:00am - 08:30pm
Monday - Friday 10:30am - 08:30pm
```

expected results:

```
Monday - Friday 08:00am - 08:30pm
Saturday - Sunday 10:30am - 08:30pm
```

Cant really figure out why the `$start` and `$end` variables aren't resetting as i expect them to. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//$days are the array with the data

$days_new = array();

$current_day = current($days)[0];
$days_new[] = array(
                    "init" => key($days),
                    "end" => key($days),
                    "open" => $current_day['open'],
                    "close" => $current_day['close']
                );

foreach($days as $key => $day){
    //update end day
    if( $day[0]['open'] == $current_day['open'] 
        && $day[0]['close'] == $current_day['close'])
    {
        $days_new[count($days_new) - 1]['end'] = $key;
    }
    //create new reg
    else{
        $days_new[] = array(
                            "init" => $key,
                            "end" => $key,
                            "open" => $current_day['open'],
                            "close" => $current_day['close']
                    );
    }
    $current_day = $day[0];
}
```

to print the result you need to do something like this:

```
foreach($days_new as $key => $item){
    print $item['init'];
    $item['init'] == $item['end'] ? print " " : print " - " . $item['end'] . " ";
    print $item['open'] . " - " . $item['close'] . "\n";
}
```

The result is:

```
Monday - Friday 08:00am - 08:30pm
Saturday - Sunday 08:00am - 08:30pm
```

It only works if a day haves just one open/close hour (array). If any place open/close twice daily (or more) you need to change the code just a little bit.

[**See the code on action**](http://ideone.com/CMHBub)